# Country-Targeted Bookmarks in Microsoft Search are not working

Tags: search, office365, microsoft365

I configured bookmarks in Microsoft Search and specified a country as I want my bookmark to point to country-specific content. The problem is they are not working. Can anyone try/confirm?

How does Microsoft correlate user<->country? I.e. how does Microsoft search algorithms know that this user is from that country?
Physical IP address? Browser locale/language settings? AAD properties? Country of license assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Targeting country in Microsoft search bookmarks works only when

- Microsoft Search is integrated with Bing
- Client configured his Country/Region in Bing and use Bing to search

Credit: [Country-Targeted bookmarks in Microsoft Search: make it work](https://www.akteams.com/microsoft-365/country-targeted-bookmarks-in-microsoft-search/#make-it-work)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft fixed it recently. They implemented  “Use Azure AD locations” flag when you select country.
If you use  “Use Azure AD locations” flag - the bookmark will only appear for users with Azure AD locations that match selected countries or regions.
If cleared, the user’s IP address will be used to determine location.

[Microsoft 365 Search country-targeted bookmarks: new “Use Azure AD locations” flag](https://vladilen.com/software/microsoft-365/microsoft-search-country-targeted-bookmarks/)